# Why is my eth0 interface not detected when installing Snort?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, vmware, snort

I am trying to install Snort on Ubuntu Server in VMware. It works fine before the setting up network cards.

I've edited `/etc/network/interfaces` with the following data:

```
#######Primary address

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.1.1 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.1.0 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 
gateway 192.168.1.1

#######second address

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
```

Then I do

```
ifconfig eth1 up
```

After when I try to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

It works fine, but when enter

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 up
```

it gives error

```
eth1: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

I have also tried, without root

```
sudo service networking restart
```

No effect. Can anyone help me out with this? Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu server, the network card will only be detected once at the first boot up.

You need to delete something

```
$rm -rf /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

change

nano /etc/default/snort

ALLOW_UNAVAILABLE="yes"

and /etc/snort/snort.debian.conf

DEBIAN_SNORT_INTERFACE="eth0" # or other port